# Insert data using this query

Tags: php

```
$korder = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","","korders");

$kio="INSERT INTO `$kioskid`(ordid,odid,oimage,obimage,obprice,oshipc,ofigures,odprice,oquantity,owarpt,oweftt,owarpc,oweftc,zari,sprice,oprice,status,address,payment,shipdate) VALUES('$ofetordid','$ofetdid','$ofetimg','$ofetbimg','$ofetbprice','$ofetshipc','$ofetfig','$ofetprice','$ofetquant','$ofetwarpt','$ofetweftt','$ofetwarpc','$ofetweftc','$ofetzari','$sprice','$sqprice','$status','$address','$payment','$shipdate')";
mysqli_query($korder,$kio);
```

The above query is not working...! I don't know what the error is behind that query.

Comment: Before you attempt to do this in PHP, have you tried using pure SQL in MYSQL?

Comment: $res = mysqli_query($korder,$kio);  if(!$res){
  echo("Error description: " . mysqli_error($korder));
  }

Comment: check if your database name is correct and also the table name

Answer (score 0):

The query should have the table name in the insert statement:

Instead of

```
INSERT INTO `$kioskid`
```

Should be

```
INSERT INTO table_name
```

Unless you are sure the variable `$kioskid` holds the table name.

Answer (score 0):

Try to build query like this:

`"INSERT INTO ".$kioskid." (ordid,odid,..) VALUES ('".$ofetordid."','".$ofetdid."',..)"`